# What is the second paramenter of TCPSocket.send in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets, send

I am using this line to send a message via a Ruby (1.8.7) socket:

```
@@socket.send login_message, 0
```

(This works fine)

What is the second parameter for? I can't find the send method in the Ruby API docs...

I first thought that it was some C style length of the message. This is why I used login_message.length as second parameter. That worked but I encountered a strange behavior:

Everything works fine when the second parameter is a odd number. If it's an even number the last character gets lost at receiving on the other side (The other side is a C++ program with a C socket). I inspected the network traffic with Wireshark and noticed that the packets look good. All the data is complete. Why is the last character lost when I receive it?

Thank you
Lennart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the flags parameter, the same as the last parameter to the [`send()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html) system call.  Normally it should be 0, but may be something like `Socket::MSG_OOB` (to send out-of-band data).  For Ruby 1.9 this is documented under [BasicSocket](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/BasicSocket.html#M001746).